# Have a two tone effect colour in an android background

Tags: android

I want to know if it is possible to have a background colour for a textview that is two toned. For example if I can specify left as black and right as white and the in-between would fill effectually black to dark grey to grey to light grey to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible, that's called a Gradient.

simple example:

gradient_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#6586F0"
        android:endColor="#4B6CD6"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

then just set the view background to `R.drawable.gradient_background`

Comment: I have been thinking for ages what it would be called! Gradient. Will look it up more. Can I make it dynamic

Comment: Yes, it can be dynamic too. The class this XML resolves to is called 'GradientDrawable'. Just check the docs for how to built one.